# How to do UI Automation of Metro-Style Apps?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, ui-automation

I've downloaded and installed the windows 8 consumer preview, and I'd like to figure out how to use the UI Automation API's to get data from metro style applications.

Background: I have a lot of automated tests which use the [Microsoft UI Automation API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294%28VS.85%29.aspx) to interact with applications. The scripts are written in IronRuby against .NET 4

Initially, I'd simply like to check if the start menu is visible (and if so, close it)

[According to Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/14/enabling-accessibility.aspx), the normal UI Automation API's should be able to access and control metro style applications, but the problem is, I can't figure out how my code can actually access the UI of metro applications? Our normal way of viewing UI automation data is using [UISpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx), however when I run UI spy under windows 8 and bring up a metro app, there is no mention of it... it seems like metro apps (including the start screen) are walled off from the desktop.

If I can't find the metro apps in UISpy, how can I find what their automation ID's are, and how could I find them from my automated test scripts?

Comment: For clarification - are you using the XAML stack or HTML5? I don't know for sure because I have not tried doing UI automation in either of these, but I think it might be a little bit different depending on your choice.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.automation.aspx

Comment: I'm not writing metro apps yet, at this stage I'd just like to view the start screen (and possibly some of the built in metro apps such as mail), which I would guess are Xaml/C++ ??

Answer (score 5):

A few resources on UI automation which works in Metro style apps:

- Here is a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/UI-Automation-Document-24a37c82) demonstrating it.
- Here is a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2011/05/18/building-ui-automation-client-applications-in-c-and-c.aspx) explaining it.
- This is a [forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/498588ae-51c0-43c9-8f31-e3d960f00297) on the subject.

  There is nothing about the app that stops traditional UI automation from working correctly.  You may have to get updated tools to view the Metro style apps.  Some ship with the Consumer Preview.  Look for inspect.exe.

Comment: By the way, inspect.exe can be found on a win8 RTM machine under c:\program files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86

Answer (score 2):

UI Automation tools can automate Metro applications. Check [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/windows.html) for example.

Stating from version 6.0 a number of features in RIATest are specifically targeted at Metro style application automation, particularly:

- Ability to stay on top of Metro UI to allow you to simultaneously see your Metro application and RIATest IDE and minimize switching from Desktop to Metro screens when automating a Metro application.
- Recording of actions performed on native Windows GUI elements (including Metro GUI). The recorder analyses your script code and reuses your variable names to generate cleaner recorded scripts similar to how you would hand-code an automation script.
- Seamless workaround for [bugs like this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779279/ui-automation-tree-is-broken-for-windows-8-store-application) in Windows UI Automation implementation in Metro UI.

*Disclaimer: I work for Cogitek, the RIATest company.*

Answer (score 1):

WinRT (aka "Metro Style") applications run in an sandbox. You cannot pierce the walls between applications, including to Desktop applications. This includes network isolation  (you cannot refer back to localhost for example except in a development environment). There are a couple of exceptions to this such as the Share and Search contacts which allow for very specific types of interactions between apps.

It is this sandbox that is preventing UISpy from seeing the executing WinRT application in the background. I'm not sure how UISpy could work around this issue without some kind of  development environment exception to the sandbox (similar to the network isolation exception) that isn't available in the consumer preview.

I'm also unaware of any announcements regarding when/if the UI Automation API will be supported for WinRT applications at this time.