# First "hello, world" test case in Eclipse from LeanFT 14.50

Tags: java, eclipse, leanft

I try to create my first test case in LeanFT for that I downloaded from Microsoft Store - One Note app. First of all I would like to learn how to press a button, for example **"Home"** button.

I tried to select **"Home"** menu using Object Identification Center (OIC) but I couldn't create identifications for that menu - it seems that OIC doesn't see **"Home"** menu and highlight a much larger area -

[image: Screenshot]

Are there any features how to work with apps from Microsoft Store?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any features how to work with apps from Microsoft Store?

Yes.
But, that's not really what you're asking.

As you probably saw in LeanFT settings, there are multiple technologies available, most of them disabled.
If I remember correctly, by default the ones enabled are WPF, STD Win, and some other.

What are these technologies?

They are the ones in which the app (the AUT) were written.
You need to know this information if you want to use LeanFT, OIC, etc.

So - the first question you need to ask is: **In what technology is my AUT** (*OneNote in your case*) **written?**

The next question is: **Is this technology enabled in settings?**

After you enabled it and restarted the engine so that the technology can be taken into account - then you can start using the OIC.

And I suggest only keeping enabled the technologies needed. There's only so much guessing the engine can do. If you have only one tech enabled, the engine knows exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi Adelin, thank you for helping me! I tried to enable separately each technology which is available in Engine and Object Identification Settings - Web, Mobile, WPF, Java...PowerBuilder. Each time I restarted the engine but it didn't help me. Also I found this enhancement request https://softwaresupport.softwaregrp.com/kb/KM03014938 about UWP support which has not been resolved yet. and this question about Metro Apps (now they are called UWP) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392774/how-to-do-ui-automation-of-metro-style-apps. What do you think about it?

Comment: yes, it is possible the technology in question is not supported. try something like paint, or even the windows explorer

Comment: Yes, but in future i will have to create the same test case for another UWP app. That's why i'm trying to find workaround for it. Now i'm able to launch this app using aut, but is it possible to click at coordinates without identifying element?

public void FirstTest() throws GeneralLeanFtException, InterruptedException { // Launch the abcd Aut abcd = Desktop.launchAut("C:\\abcd.exe"); Thread.sleep(100 * 1000); }

Comment: In Java there has to be some kind of HP.SDK.LFT.Mouse. I outlined an example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48294000/3233388) answer on how to use in C#